# Delimiter "\u0001" is not recognized by Spark read fuction

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delimiter

Data I received from the operational system have delimiter as \u0001.
When I am reading the file using spark read function like code below, it does not automatically parse the data, and shows up all columns as one column. If I use other delimiter like pipe, it worked fine, but I don't prefer to use other delimiter because it is operational database. Most of times, some column has delimiter inside of the column value.

Raw Data:

```
ID\u0001NAM\u0001USER
4 \u0001 foo \u0001 bar
```

Code:

```
delimiter = "\u0001"
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("sep", delimiter).option("inferSchema", "true").csv(file_path)
```

Result:

```
|ID\u0001NAM\u0001USER|
|4 \u0001 foo \u0001 bar|
```

Did I do something wrong here? It used to work with other system.

Comment: Is the data stored by Hive using its default delimiter?  Can you try with '\x01' as delimiter?

Comment: @Bala It is actually csv file and stored in Data Lake